# Uploading files directly to Amazon S3 from Ember JS

Tags: javascript, canvas, amazon-web-services, ember.js, amazon-s3

I am using [ember uploader](https://github.com/benefitcloud/ember-uploader) in order to upload files directly to Amazon S3 from my client once I have signed the image upload on the server as described [here](https://github.com/benefitcloud/ember-uploader#uploading-to-s3)

Now what I am trying to do is resize the image to create a thumbnail before uploading to Amazon S3. This way I'll have two images to upload to Amazon S3. One will be the original image and the other will be the thumbnail created.

At the moment I am using a HTML 5 canvas in order to resize the image:

```
var MAX_HEIGHT = 300;
function render(src){
  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    if(image.height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
      image.width *= MAX_HEIGHT / image.height;
      image.height = MAX_HEIGHT;
    }
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);

  };
  image.src = src;
}
```

I am able to resize the image in the HTML 5 canvas. The problem I am facing is that I am battling to then get the image back into a File Object for the Ember Uploader to sign and send over to Amazon S3.

This is the code that handles the actual upload:

```
if (!Ember.isEmpty(files)) {
  uploader.upload(files[0]); // Uploader will send a sign request then upload to S3
}
```

As you can see, the first item of the FileList array is being uploaded. I would like to be able to append the canvas' thumbnail image to this FileList in order to iterate over the FileList and then sign and upload both images to Amazon S3.

I know that a canvas can be converted to a data url using canvas.toDataURL but is it possible to covert a canvas to a File Object or should I do the resize and upload in a different way?

Thanks!

Comment: did you solved this Issue ?